# chrome not getting triggered while running the script using CI Tool Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am learning using selenium with jenkins ,
prepare one script
""  @Test

```
public void helloJenkin()
{
    System.out.println("hello Jenin");
    String path="D:\\Selenium\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path );
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,5000);
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}"""
```

This script run perfectly alright while running using command prompt.
But while using Jenkins ,I am getting below error

#

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace C:\Users\jeetendra\Desktop\jenkinsDemo
[jenkinsDemo] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson7643820465261394286.bat

C:\Users\jeetendra Tiwari\Desktop\jenkinsDemo>run.bat

C:\Users\jeetendra Tiwari\Desktop\jenkinsDemo>java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\jeetendra Tiwari\Desktop\jenkinsDemo\testng.xml

hello Jenin
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (03903626326234d6eb0d5d0934646634634934aab9eed) on port 12185
Only local connections are allowed.
===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

#

can you please help here why chrome is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that chrome is installed on server where Jenkins is running.
On the same server verify path of chrome driver.

You can install Xvnc plugin on Jenkins which will show you if browser is opened or not and you can see actual test cases running on that jenkins server.

To add plugin follow the steps

1. Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins
2. Click on Available tab
3. Search for Xvnc
4. Click on "Install Without Restart" button

Comment: HI Akash, Thanks for Reply. how and where to set the path of chrome driver.

Comment: If your Jenkins server is running on Linux, then you can create directory at any location. Put chrome driver inside the directory  and give the full path.Consider you have created directory "Drivers" inside home, then it would be                                                                                          path="home//Drivers//ChromeDriver//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe";

Comment: Akash , client and server are on same machine,I am using windows.

Comment: can anyone Please help me here.

Comment: I have already used that link , it doesn't say anything about this problem

Comment: any one help me here

Comment: Jeetendra, just try one thing. instead of opening chrome browser, open Firefox and if it is working fine then you will be sure that issue will be of chrome driver path.

Comment: If chrome driver path is the issue then there is plugin available in jenkins "Chromedriver Plugin". Try to install it.you will end up with a $JENKINS_HOME\tools\chromedriver\chromedrive.exe which you can refer to in the Jenkins Selenium plugin configuration for Chrome[driver] binary path as tools\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe

Comment: go through this link which explains about how to set path of chrome driver. It might be help you. "https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/-3LJ3wma3RE"

Comment: Thanks Akash.I will try n let you know

Comment: I had uninstall the Jenkins and reinstall it via cmd and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add try and catch block to your Selenium code, something like -
---------Example-----------

public class chrome[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Xu2.jpg) {

```
@Test
public void sampleApp() 
{

    try
    {
        WebDriver driver;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\workspace\\Jenkins_Selenium\\ChromeLaunch\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.out.println("Hello Google...");
        System.out.println("Successfully Launched the browser...");
        driver.get("http:\\localhost:8080");
        System.out.println("Successfully Executed the URL...");
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Successfully Executed The flow...");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Successfully Executed with exceptions..");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

this might work but if still your test cases are failing , one more thing you have to do..its generally done when you are executing Jenkins & Selenium on cloud machine in your company network and authentication is needed because it might blocking , so what you have to do is-

just press windows+R key and type services.msc, all the services running on your desktop will open just go to jenkins
like in Capture1 image right click and open properties as in Capture2 image , than go to Log on tab, in that select (**This account**) and give your credentials by browse your name and password and confirm password , after giving your credential press okay ,now again go back to general tab and stop and start the jenkins service.
Now go back to your jenkins url and try to execute your Selenium script with jenkins.

-----hope this will help-----